# how to assign a ruby file object to an assets_attributes via rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end
```

I'd like to do something like via the rails console:

```
f=File.new '/Users/jt/em.jpg'
u=User.find(21)
u.assets_attributes=f
```

But I get:

```
ArgumentError: Hash or Array expected, got File (#<File:/Users/jt/em.jpg>)
```

How would I assign this correctly?

thx in advance

Comment: You want to store a JPEG in one of the asset attributes?

Comment: yeah, I've tried making it as an Asset (I'm using paperclip) but still no dice.

Comment: You might have better luck if you read the file into memory first. Then maybe throw it in a hash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that you need to assign an array to `u.assets_attributes`. You gave it a File object. Try replacing the last line with `u.assets_attributes=[f]`. Since it is expecting an array. Let me know.

Comment: hmm.... NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<Asset:0x007fa48902f758> let me look into this more. Prob need to assign as an asset first rather than a file